# Getting 403 when adding to stylesheets block in symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

I am trying to include certain stylesheets from specific bundles along with all the shared stylesheets but when I include the path below, I get a 403 Forbidden error. Am I just using the wrong syntax? Thanks for all the help in advance!

here is the block

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/workspace/symfony/src/Starnes/TaskBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

and I get this as a result

```
GET http://localhost/workspace/symfony/src/Starnes/TaskBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css 403 (Forbidden)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it to work by changing the url so instead of it accessing the files in the `src` folder it accesses them from the `web/bundle/.../css` directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use syntax like  @AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/css/...

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html